# How do I show multiple fields in a ViewBag drop down list for asp-items in asp.net-mvc-core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Model

```
 public partial class Official
    {
        public short OfficialNo { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 2 partial answers but neither gives me what I want:

In my controller on Edit:

ViewBag.OfficialNo = new SelectList(_context.Official, "OfficialNo", "OfficialNo", "", "Surname"); 
This gives me

```
    Smith
    111
    Brown
    102
    Gray
    103
```

The top line is bold and comes from "Surname" which is supposed to be the Data Group Field. The bottom line is what is stored in the database and displays a value if there is one (which is correct).

Alternatively

ViewBag.OfficialNo = new SelectList(_context.Official.Select(e => e.OfficialNo + " - " + e.Firstname + " " + e.Surname));

This gives me

```
    101 – John Smith
    102 – Bob Brown
    103 – Garry Gray
```

which is the info I want but does not allow a selection to be stored (naturally).

I want

```
    John Smith
    111
    Bob Brown
    102
    Garry Gray
    103
```

so that the first line is info and the second line (if selected) will be what is stored on update.

**How do I combine the 2 ViewBag statements above ?**

For further info my Edit View statement is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="RefereeNo" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="RefereeNo" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.OfficialNo"><option>   </option></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution is to add Group property of SelectListItem :

Controller :

```
var officials = _context.Official.GroupBy(x => x.Firstname+" "+x.Surname);

List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var official in officials)
{
    var optionGroup = new SelectListGroup() { Name = official.Key };
    foreach (var item in official)
    {
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.OfficialNo.ToString(), Text = item.OfficialNo.ToString(), Group = optionGroup });
    }
}

ViewBag.OfficialNo = selectListItems;
```

Then in view show/bind the dropdownlist :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@item.RefereeNo" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="@item.RefereeNo" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.OfficialNo"><option>   </option></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nan Yu, the change to the controller worked fine. One query (most probably misunderstanding), I did not have to change my edit view, in fact if I do I get an error on the inclusion of @item. (does not exist in current context). ??

Comment: @Rod , yes , you don't need to change your view . your code should work after changing the server side codes.

Comment: In addition, please consider accept the reply as answer ,which may help others who meet same problem .

Comment: @Rod , Please mark answer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Not repeat the solution as a reply .

Answer (score 0):

As per Nan Yu's answer above:

Controller :

```
var officials = _context.Official.GroupBy(x => x.Firstname+" "+x.Surname);

List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var official in officials)
{
    var optionGroup = new SelectListGroup() { Name = official.Key };
    foreach (var item in official)
    {
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.OfficialNo.ToString(), Text = item.OfficialNo.ToString(), Group = optionGroup });
    }
}

ViewBag.OfficialNo = selectListItems;
```